# Want to use Script recorded for OFT(OATS) in OLT(OATS) module.Any suggestions on how?

Tags: openscript

I am currently working on Open Script(OATS) Version: 12.3.0.1 Build 376.
Scenario is that I have written/recorded multiple scripts using 
Functional Testing (Browser/GUI Automation) Web Module but now I want to 
run the same scripts on Load Testing (Protocol Automation) Web/HTTP 
module.

To be more clear thing is like that when we record scripts using 
Functional testing modules, during playback browser opens up and re-runs 
your script on a machine.

But unfortunately now i want those scripts to be ran on EM Machines 
where no browsers are there.More precisely scripts run in silent mode 
without any browser getting launched.

Problem with Load modules scripts is that they run on HTTP protocol and 
same doesn't gives you lot of customization option as functional module 
scripts give you as they work on DOM structures and same is supported in 
webdom module.

In open source community(Selenium) scenarios like this are handled 
through HtmlUnitDriver.
I tried with the same in open script by adding external jars as an asset 
in the script but that gave me the linkage error.

Any suggestions on how we can achieve the above task would be

appreciated.

Regards

Ankur shrivastava

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htmlunit` as an asset in your loadtest script, however there are some conflicts with xml/html parsing libraries used by `htmlunit` with the ones openscript uses (for reporting). Two options:

1. Remove the xerces/xalan libs from your `htmlunit.jar`, thus making `htmlunit` depending on the openscript libs. This might cause issues with versioning or some `htmlunit` functions break.
2. Remove the xerces/xalan libs from openscript script; just remove `oracle.oats.jagent.lib3rdparty` from the script `MANIFEST.MF`. This ensures htmlunit uses its own libs. However loadtest reporting will break.